# Where are the different app icon sizes submitted through the app developer site used?

Tags: icons, application-development

When I submit an application through the app developer process in [MyApps](http://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com), I'm asked to submit icons in different sizes: 128px, 64px, 32px, 16px.

[image]

Where is each of these icon sizes used when my app is in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first glance:

**128**: App details view in the Software Center, Alt-tab Switcher

**64** : Dash, and resized to 48 for the Launcher and the Software Center tiled view

**32** : Software Center list view

**16** : Some places on the desktop (Nautilus list view?) and probably in the software updater for 12.10 (https://twitter.com/dylanmccall/status/205418733206904833/photo/1/large)